# WCF trying to expose a nettcp endpoint; TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I don't understand what the problem is here. My wsHttpBinding works fine. Here is my configuration. Any help most appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  .....
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DataService.Service1Behavior"
               name="ODHdotNET.DataService">
        <endpoint 
               address="" 
               binding="wsHttpBinding" 
               bindingConfiguration="largeTransferwsHttpBinding"
               contract="ODHdotNET.IDataService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint 
            address="net.tcp://139.149.141.221:8001/DataService.svc" 
            binding="netTcpBinding" 
            contract="ODHdotNET.IDataService"/>
        <endpoint 
            address="mex" 
            binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://139.149.141.221:8000/DataService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="largeTransferwsHttpBinding2" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000">
          <security mode ="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="largeTransferwsHttpBinding" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DataService.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

edit: I am self-hosting in a Windows Service; I am not using IIS.

Comment: I was configuring the wrong configuration file. However, now that I have configured the correct one I get the following error:

"Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://139.149.141.221:8001/DataService.svc'.

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:05:00'.

Comment: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

In response to a post below I have run netstat and I get:

TCP 139.149.141.221:8001 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 4960

It is not the firewall, no ports are being blocked.

If I try to use a port I know that works (for example for http and switching the http endpoint off) it still doesn't work.

Comment: @fugu i know this is very very old post, but we are facing the same issue with windows service and it is intermittent, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean that a WCF client throws this error ? 
if so:
please run the follwing at the command prompt:
netstat -ona | find "8001"
if this returns data, please post it

Comment: OK , so the host is up and running , no other program is on this port. now, i think the base address you provided is too specific. can you try to remove the ':8000/DataService.svc' part? (the base address is used by endpoints. they add the rest of the uri)

Comment: Hi @Roel look like you forgot to put the port number in double quotes like so: "8001"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add TCP support to your IIS.
To enable TCP, MSMQ, or named pipes communication specifically, perform the additional step of configuring support for the associated protocol. For TCP communication, bind the default Web site to a net.tcp port by using the Appcmd command-line utility. Appcmd is an IIS utility that enables you to administer virtual sites, directories,applications, and application pools.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -
+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='808:*']
```

To support the other protocols, run additional commands that enable those protocols for the default Web site. At this point, you have configured the net.tcp protocol at the site level.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/OrderServiceHost"
/enabledProtocols:http,net.tcp
```

Please look at these for more detail: [Extend Your WCF Services Beyond HTTP With WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx)

[Hosting WCF Services in Windows Activation Service](http://www.devx.com/VistaSpecialReport/Article/33831/1954)

Comment: Many thanks. Please see my edit, I am not using IIS to host but I will read this and see if it is a lead.

Answer (score 0):

***Make sure the port is open in windows firewall***

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your host is running when you invoke methods in client application.